# Why socket.io drops my entire server when emitting 2 events at the same time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, sockets

I'm building an e-commerce with chat. I have 2 react apps, a customer's app, and a owner's/admin's app. I can send from customer to admin in real time messages in chat/:customer component, but I want at the same time to emit an event to admin's navbar to update the inbox messages, so when a message is sent to be notified real time. Once I created this, and send a message from customer, on page refresh the entire node js server drops. Why does this happen? Bellow you can see my code:

Owner/admin NavBar(This drops my server):

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faAngleDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import "../css/navBar.css"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { socket } from "./privateChat";

export const NavBar = () => {


    /*I added useEffect, because otherwise the function catalogueChoices()
      works only on second click!*/
    useEffect(() => {
                        let addProduct = document.getElementById("addProduct")
                        let preview = document.getElementById("preview")

                        addProduct.style.display = "none"
                        preview.style.display = "none"   
                        
                        socket.on('new message', (data) => console.log(data))

                        return () => {
                            socket.off('new message', (data) => console.log(data))
                        }
                    }, [])

 
    
    //The function that shows and hide the cataloque submenu on nav-bar.
    const catalogueChoices = () => {

                                    let addProduct = document.getElementById("addProduct")
                                    let preview = document.getElementById("preview")
                                    let catalogue = document.getElementById("catalogue")
                                    let display = preview.style.display

                                    if(display === "none"){
                                        addProduct.style.display = "initial"
                                        preview.style.display = "initial"
                                        catalogue.style.height = "150px"
                                    } else {
                                        addProduct.style.display = "none"
                                        preview.style.display = "none"
                                        catalogue.style.height = "70px"
                                    }                                
                                }

    
    return( <div className="navBar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="catalogue">
                        <p>Products
                            <span>
                                <button onClick={ catalogueChoices } className="angleDown" >
                                    < FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faAngleDown } />
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <Link id="addProduct" className="products" to="add-product">Add Product</Link>
                        <Link id="preview" className="products" to="preview">Preview</Link>
                    </li>                  
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/">Orders</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/">Customers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <a  href="#/chat" >Inbox <span id="newMessage"> { newMessage } </span></a>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
           )
}
```

Owner/admin private chat component(works fine without navbar socket)

```
import "../css/chat.css"
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { showMessage } from "../functions/chat";
import axios from "axios"   

//Initializing socket.io and url's parameter name object.
export const socket = io(`http://localhost:5000`)

/*Below component is dynamically generated in order to chat with
  a specific customer that sent us a message*/
export const PrivateChat = () => {
    
    //The state needed.
    const [messagesHistory, setMessagesHistory ] = useState([])
    
    
    const params = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
                    //Holding customer's name from url in a variable.
                    let customer = params.customer 

                    //Fetching all the old messages to be displayed.
                    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/chat-messages')
                         .then( res => {
                                        let messages = res.data.filter(item => item.Customer === customer)
                                        if(messagesHistory.length !== messages.length) setMessagesHistory(messages)                                       
                                        })
                    
                    //Handling the socket.io event that will send us a message from admin and displaying it.
                    socket.on('customer '+ params.customer, (data)=> {  let sender = data.sender === 'admin' ? 'me' : data.sender
                                                                        let message = data.message
                                                                        if(data.sender !== 'admin') showMessage(sender, message)
                                                                    })
                    
                    return () => {
                        socket.off('customer '+ params.customer, (data)=> {  let sender = data.sender === 'admin' ? 'me' : data.sender
                                                                             let message = data.message
                                                                             if(data.sender !== 'admin') showMessage(sender, message)
                    })
                    }
                    
                    }, [])
    /*The function to send a message to a customer in real time,
      saving it in the database and displaying it.*/
    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        let username = params.customer
        let message = document.getElementById("input").value
        let data = { username: username,
                     message: message,
                     sender: 'admin'
                    }
        
        socket.emit('chat message', data)
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/chat-messages', data )
        showMessage("me", message)
    }

     return(<div className="chat">
                <ul id="messages">
                    { messagesHistory.map( item => <li>{(item.Sender === "admin" ? "me" : item.Sender) + ": " + item.Message}</li>) }                    
                </ul>
                <form id="form" action="" onSubmit={sendMessage}>
                    <input id="input" /><button>Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>)
}
```

customer's app:

```
import "../css/chat.css"
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { showMessage } from "../functions/chat";
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

//The dynamically created component we are redirected to when we enter our username to chat with admin.
export const Chat = () => {    
    
    //The state needed
    const [messagesHistory, setMessagesHistory ] = useState([])

    //Initializing socket.io and url's parameter name object.
    const socket = io(`http://localhost:5000`);
    const params = useParams() 

    useEffect( () => {
                        //Holding customer's name from url in a variable.
                        let customer = params.username 

                        //Fetching all the old messages to be displayed.
                        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/chat-messages')
                            .then(res =>  { 
                                            let messages = res.data.filter(item => item.Customer === customer)
                                            if(messagesHistory.length !== messages.length) setMessagesHistory(messages)
                                            })
                                                                                    
                        
                        //Handling the socket.io event that will send us a message from a specific customer and displaying it.
                        socket.on('customer '+ customer, (data) => { let sender = data.sender === customer? 'me' : 'admin'
                                                                    let message = data.message
                                                                    if(data.sender === 'admin') showMessage(sender, message)
                                                                    console.log(0)
                                                                    })                
                    }, [])  

 
    /*The function to send a message to the admin in real time,
      saving it in the database and displaying it.*/
    const sendMessage =  (e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          
          let username = params.username 
          let sender = params.username         
          let message = document.getElementById("input").value   
          
          let data = { sender: sender,
                       message: message,
                       username: username
                     }

          socket.emit('chat message', data)
                    
          axios.post('http://localhost:5000/chat-messages', data )
          showMessage("me", message)
        } 

    return(<div className="chat">
                <ul id="messages">
                    { messagesHistory.map( item => <li>{(item.Sender === "admin"? "admin" : "me") + ": " + item.Message}</li>) } 
                </ul>
                <form id="form" action="" onSubmit={ sendMessage } >
                    <input id="input" /><button>Send</button>
                </form>
           </div>)
}
```

The common server for socket.io and shared Apis:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
//Creating a new server for socket.io with express
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
//The socket.io server instance attached to an instance of http.Server.
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
                                cors: {
                                origin: "*",
                                methods: ["GET", "POST"],
                                }
                            })
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const cors = require("cors")
const db = require('./database/db')

//The middlewares needed to exchange data with frontend.
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json())

//db.query("DELETE FROM chat_messages")

//------> Socket.io configurations. <------
io.on('connection', (socket) => {   
    
   /*When server receives a message from a customer or admin, we dynamically create an event
     depending on customer's name, and emit it with the message to both parties.  */
   socket.on('chat message', (data) => {

         let name = data.username
         let sender = data.sender
         let message = data.message

         io.emit('customer ' + name, { message: message,
                                       sender: sender})
         io.emit('new message', 1)
   }) 
 
})


//Importing routes
const productsRoute = require("./routes/products")
const chatRoute = require("./routes/chat")

app.use('/products', productsRoute)
app.use('/chat-messages', chatRoute)


server.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution alone. When i emit message and at the same time axios.post to save it, crushes the connection with the database and doesnt fetch anything. I had to save it from the server while grabbed from server side socket.io. Why there is anywhere this detail? Am I Columbus who found socket.io message saving?!!